# How to know variable such as 'OpenCV' in CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am using OpenCV with gcc and cmake. And I found a tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html .In the file `CMakeLists.txt`, there are some variables such as `OpenCV` and `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(VideoRecord)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(VideoRecord main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(VideoRecord ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

**I want to know where to find these variables definition.**

## EDIT

Thanks @qbranchmaster's answer. I tried to search `FindOpenCV.cmake` but failed.

First try.

```
➜  ~ cmake --help-module-list | grep "FindOpen"
FindOpenACC
FindOpenAL
FindOpenCL
FindOpenGL
FindOpenMP
FindOpenSSL
FindOpenSceneGraph
FindOpenThreads
```

Another try.

```
➜  / find . "FindOpenCV.cmake"
```

**In addition, my os is osx and I install `cmake` with `brew`. I comiple and install `OpenCV` manually.**

Comment: @usr1234567 I can run my demo sucessfully and it means `cmake` can find these variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These variables are part of the package config script shipping with OpenCV.

Note that [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_package.html) is a two-headed beast. The classic mode of operation is finding libraries [through find-scripts](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#find-module-packages). This is still the approach being used today for third-party libraries that are not aware of CMake. However, if your dependency is itself being built with CMake, it can provide [a package config file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#package-configuration-file) instead, which allows for a more powerful mode of operation.

The idea here is that instead of you telling CMake how to find a dependency, the dependency *itself* tells CMake how clients can find it. This is the approach that is taken by libraries like OpenCV and Qt.

To answer your question, those variables are being set by the package config file in your local OpenCV installation, the template of which [can be found in the OpenCV source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in) under `cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in`.

Answer (score 0):

They are defined in CMake OpenCV module. CMake has numerous modules that aid in finding various libraries like OpenCV (FindOpenCV.cmake module). 
Using this command you can get a list of modules that your CMake supports:

```
cmake --help-module-list
```

Some libraries come with their own *.cmake modules which should be installed in some system path. If you are using Ubuntu, your cmake modules should be localised in:

```
 /usr/share/cmake/Modules/
```

If not, just search system for file FindOpenCV.cmake. In that file you will find these variables.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you get variable names from the documentation or source code of the package you want to find.

Often you can derive the name to put into `find_package` from the provided FindFoo.cmake module file name, because "Foo" would be the name. The find module is either part of CMake or comes with the third-party library.
If there is no find module, some modules provide FooConfig.cmake files, where "Foo" is again the string to put into `find_package`.
If you have neither a find nor a config file, you need to find the library by other means, e.g., FindPkgConfig or `find_library` / `find_file`.